# RecyclerView not showing after back button pressed on actionbar

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-recyclerview

Hi am building an app where the MainActivity shows a GridView of some categories. When each category is clicked another Activity(GridItemActivity) opens with some RecyclerView. Also when the RecyclerView is clicked GalleryActivity opens to show the content(ImageView and TextView) for the list selected. In the Manifest file I have set each Activity's parents as shown below:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gridrecycler">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".GalleryActivity">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".GridItemActivity"/>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".GridItemActivity" >
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity"/>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The problem is:

1. When I click on the back icon on the ActionBar of GalleryActivity, the GridActivity shows up expectedly  but then with no content(my RecyclerView items doesn't show). Also ActionBar title changes to App name.
2. On the recycler Adapter what is the best method of setting the onClick Listener. Should it be on the onBindViewHolder method or in the ViewHolder class or where should it be. If its at the ViewHolder class then please show me how to implement that in my code because am kind of missing something.

GridItemActivity.java

```
package com.example.gridrecycler;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GridItemActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private ArrayList<String> mNames = new ArrayList<>();

    private int[] images = {
            R.drawable.apples,R.drawable.bakes,R.drawable.banana,R.drawable.craves,
            R.drawable.grapes,R.drawable.orange,R.drawable.pineapple,R.drawable.redgrapes,
            R.drawable.strawberrys,R.drawable.watermelons
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid_item);
        //enable back Button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: started");

        Log.d(TAG, "getIncomingItent: checking for incoming intents");
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("name")){
            Log.d(TAG, "getIncomingItent: found intent extra");

            String categoryName = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
            setActionBarTitle(categoryName);

            initImageBitmaps();
        }
    }

    private void setActionBarTitle(String title)
    {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }

    private void initImageBitmaps(){
        Log.d(TAG, "initImageBitmaps: preparing bitmaps");

        mNames.add("Apple");
        mNames.add("Bakes");
        mNames.add("Banana");
        mNames.add("Craves");
        mNames.add("Grapes");
        mNames.add("Oranges");
        mNames.add("Pineapple");
        mNames.add("Pepper");
        mNames.add("Strawberry");
        mNames.add("Watermelon");

        initRecyclerView();
    }

    private void initRecyclerView(){
        Log.d(TAG, "initRecyclerView: init recyclerview");
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, mNames, images);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }
}
```

RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
package com.example.gridrecycler;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewAdapter";

    private ArrayList<String> mImageNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private int[] mImages;
    private Context mContext;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> mImageNames, int[] mImages) {
        this.mImageNames = mImageNames;
        this.mImages = mImages;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_listitem, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view, mContext, mImages, mImageNames);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called");
        viewHolder.image.setImageResource(mImages[i]);
        viewHolder.imageName.setText(mImageNames.get(i));
        viewHolder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked on : "+mImageNames.get(i));
                Toast.makeText(mContext, mImageNames.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, GalleryActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("image_url", mImages[i]);
                intent.putExtra("image_name", mImageNames.get(i));
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mImageNames.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        ImageView image;
        TextView imageName;
        RelativeLayout parentLayout;
        int[] images;
        ArrayList<String> mImageNames = new ArrayList<>();
        Context context;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, Context context, int[] images, ArrayList<String> mImageNames) {
            super(itemView);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            imageName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_name);
            parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            this.context = context;
            this.images = images;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, GalleryActivity.class);
            //intent.putExtra("image_url", mImages[getAdapterPosition()]);
            //intent.putExtra("image_name", mImageNames.get(getAdapterPosition()));
            //mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

GalleryActivity.java

```
package com.example.gridrecycler;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "GalleryActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: started");
        getIncomingIntent();

    }

    private void getIncomingIntent()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "getIncomingItent: checking for incoming intents");
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("image_url") && getIntent().hasExtra("image_name")){
            Log.d(TAG, "getIncomingItent: found intent extra");

            int imageUrl = getIntent().getIntExtra("image_url", 000);
            String imageName = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_name");
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(imageName);

            setImage(imageUrl, imageName);
        }
    }

    private void setImage(int imageUrl, String imageName){
        Log.d(TAG, "setImage: setting image url and name to widgets");
        TextView name = findViewById(R.id.image_description);
        name.setText(imageName);

        ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageResource(imageUrl);
    }
}
```

Sorry for asking too much in a question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question one(1), this solved the problem.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

For the second one, this helped

```
public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, Context context, int[] images, ArrayList<String> mImageNames) {
        super(itemView);
        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_name);
        parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.context = context;
        this.images = images;
        this.mImageNames = mImageNames;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, GalleryActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("image_url", mImages[getAdapterPosition()]);
        intent.putExtra("image_name", mImageNames.get(getAdapterPosition()));
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
```